# What exactly gets changed when I run "cordova platform update android"

Tags: android, cordova, svn, platform

I have an existing running project that had cordova-3.x.x.jar file in the lib folder inside platforms/android and recently I updated cordova with

```
cordova platform update android
```

and deleted the old jar file. Everything was working fine and i checked in my code to SVN. Now, whenever I check out fresh copy of the project, it shows me bunch of "cannot find symbol" errors when i run

```
cordova build android
```

but if after check out, I run `cordova platform update android` first, then the build is successful and app runs as expected.

I tried a lot to find out what changes after i run platform update cmd that makes everything work again but haven't found any clue. It does not create any jar file.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing here?

Here are the errors that I get if i do not do `cordova platform update android` (`cordova.js` show 4.0.2 inside asset folder)

```
CordovaLib:compileDebugJava
/.../platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/App.java:194: error: cannot find symbol
        webView.bindButton(override);
               ^
  symbol:   method bindButton(boolean)
  location: variable webView of type CordovaWebView
/.../platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/App.java:206: error: cannot find symbol
        webView.bindButton(button, override);
               ^
  symbol:   method bindButton(String,boolean)
  location: variable webView of type CordovaWebView
/.../platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/App.java:215: error: cannot find symbol
        return webView.isBackButtonBound();
                      ^
  symbol:   method isBackButtonBound()
  location: variable webView of type CordovaWebView
/.../platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaChromeClient.java:216: error: cannot find symbol
        if (url.startsWith("file://") || Config.isUrlWhiteListed(url)) {
                                               ^
  symbol:   method isUrlWhiteListed(String)
  location: class Config
/.../platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaChromeClient.java:229: error: cannot find symbol
                String r = this.appView.exposedJsApi.exec(service, action, callbackId, message);
                                       ^
  symbol:   variable exposedJsApi
  location: variable appView of type CordovaWebView
/.../platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaChromeClient.java:240: error: cannot find symbol
                this.appView.exposedJsApi.setNativeToJsBridgeMode(Integer.parseInt(message));
                            ^
  symbol:   variable exposedJsApi
  location: variable appView of type CordovaWebView
/.../platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaChromeClient.java:250: error: cannot find symbol
            String r = this.appView.exposedJsApi.retrieveJsMessages("1".equals(message));
                                   ^
  symbol:   variable exposedJsApi
  location: variable appView of type CordovaWebView
/.../platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebViewClient.java:114: error: cannot find symbol
        appView.pluginManager.exec(service, action, callbackId, jsonArgs);
               ^
  symbol:   variable pluginManager
  location: variable appView of type CordovaWebView
/.../platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebViewClient.java:128: error: cannot find symbol
        if (NativeToJsMessageQueue.ENABLE_LOCATION_CHANGE_EXEC_MODE && url.startsWith(CORDOVA_EXEC_URL_PREFIX)) {
                                  ^
  symbol:   variable ENABLE_LOCATION_CHANGE_EXEC_MODE
  location: class NativeToJsMessageQueue
/.../platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebViewClient.java:133: error: cannot find symbol
        else if ((this.appView.pluginManager != null) && this.appView.pluginManager.onOverrideUrlLoading(url)) {
                              ^
  symbol:   variable pluginManager
  location: variable appView of type CordovaWebView
/.../platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebViewClient.java:133: error: cannot find symbol
        else if ((this.appView.pluginManager != null) && this.appView.pluginManager.onOverrideUrlLoading(url)) {
                                                                     ^
  symbol:   variable pluginManager
  location: variable appView of type CordovaWebView
/.../platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebViewClient.java:217: error: cannot find symbol
            if (url.startsWith("file://") || url.startsWith("data:")  || Config.isUrlWhiteListed(url)) {
                                                                               ^
  symbol:   method isUrlWhiteListed(String)
  location: class Config
/.../platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebViewClient.java:271: error: cannot find symbol
        this.appView.jsMessageQueue.reset();
                    ^
  symbol:   variable jsMessageQueue
  location: variable appView of type CordovaWebView
/.../platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebViewClient.java:277: error: cannot find symbol
        if (this.appView.pluginManager != null) {
                        ^
  symbol:   variable pluginManager
  location: variable appView of type CordovaWebView
/.../platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebViewClient.java:278: error: cannot find symbol
            this.appView.pluginManager.onReset();
                        ^
  symbol:   variable pluginManager
  location: variable appView of type CordovaWebView
/.../client/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebViewClient.java:307: error: cannot find symbol
        this.appView.loadUrlTimeout++;
                    ^
  symbol:   variable loadUrlTimeout
  location: variable appView of type CordovaWebView
/.../platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebViewClient.java:313: error: cannot find symbol
        if (this.appView.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
                        ^
  symbol:   method getVisibility()
  location: variable appView of type CordovaWebView
/.../client/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebViewClient.java:350: error: cannot find symbol
        this.appView.loadUrlTimeout++;
                    ^
  symbol:   variable loadUrlTimeout
  location: variable appView of type CordovaWebView
/.../platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
            if ((url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:")) && !Config.isUrlWhiteListed(url)) {
                                                                                ^
  symbol:   method isUrlWhiteListed(String)
  location: class Config
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
19 errors
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Comment: cordova 3.x.x shouldn't have a cordova.jar file on the lib folder, they changed to a cordovaLib library project. cordova platform update android should update that cordovaLib project